# Can I run ELF executable from Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2 Delphi Android app?

Tags: android, delphi

I have an executable ELF file maked in NDK. Assumed the file has already deployed to the armeabi-v7a folder and has executable permission. I successfully run it from a C++ project using *system()* command passing full path to it. 
Is there a similar way to run this file from Delphi project?

Comment: Is your phone Rooted?

Comment: No, the phone is not rooted, however, the executable file is launched successfully in the 'lib' folder. Set external path to armeabi-v7a folder in the  deployment manager. The file name MUST have prefix lib and suffix .so In this case executable permission will be set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the answer himself:

uses

Posix.Stdlib;

LCMD: string;

LCMD := TPath.GetLibraryPath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'libmy.so';
_system(MarshaledAString(UTF8Encode(LCMD)));